Kafka producer send record to topic partition catch TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s)
In a real environment, flink is used to connect to kafka as the producer of Kafka. Now, the "TimeoutException" exception message appears when sending data in the environment: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for topic-test-1 due to 60024 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time
I observed the network IO and disk IO (network: 10000mbps) of the kafka server, and there is still a lot of idle time. All broker nodes in the kafka cluster are in normal state
Producer configuration:
properties
batch.size=16k
request.timeout.ms=60*1000

I am not an expert in kafka, so I am confused about why such a problem occurs. Has anyone encountered a similar problem?
help me solve this problem?
